# Vertical Alignment my items?CSS+BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=17

This is code HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
<p class="text-center" style="color:white">Hello World!</p>
<p class="text-center" style="color:white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequa</p>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="">
<p><img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/b1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </p></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="">
     <img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/b2.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="">
    <img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/b3.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
<p></p></div>
</div>
```

I want this item to be aligned vertically at the center, for all resolutions.

Currently the resolution looks like:

http://i61.tinypic.com/2wh4e4g.jpg

This is code CSS:

```
.entry-content2
{
  background:url("http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/BODY-DROP.png");
width:100%;

  height: 100vh;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?
I tried several options but unfortunately looks different in several resolutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use flex box for this!

```
.container-fluid{
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Here I used the viewport vertical unit to make the container be the frame size.
Then I make the display to be flex, and some flex-ish centering.

But, do not forget to add a div inside *.container-fluid*, like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="hola">
...(rest of content)
</div>
</div>
```

Call it whatever you like and style however you want that div, as you'd avoid a centering mess due to flex box only affecting the father div.